# Google Apps Script - How to get email addresses from Sheet2 and send email

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Spreadsheet that stores Task on on Sheet 1. When a task is completed a email is sent. Sheet 2 holds the specific email addresses for send to, cc, and reply to. I am able to loop through sheet 2 and get the email addresses for each column. I want to be able to get those email address into my options for the send email in MailApp. I am unable to get the email addresses out of the loop for sheet 2. See code below. Any help would be appreciate.

```
var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";

function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheets()[1];  

  var startRow = 2;
  var lastRow1 = sheet1.getLastRow()-1;
  var lastCol1 = sheet1.getLastColumn();
  var lastRow2 = sheet2.getLastRow()-1;
  var lastCol2 = sheet2.getLastColumn();

var sh1Range = sheet1.getRange(startRow, 1, lastRow1, lastCol1).getValues();
var sh2Range = sheet2.getRange(startRow, 1, lastRow2, lastCol2).getValues();
var subject = "Test Email";
//sheet2 Email Loop
for (var i = 0; i < sh2Range.length; ++i){
  var emails = sh2Range[i];
  var to = emails[0];
  var cc = emails[1];
  var replyTo = emails[2];
 }
//sheet1 Data Loop and Send Email
for (var j = 0; j < sh1Range.length; ++j){
  var data = sh1Range[j];
  var pName = data[0];
  var pID = data[1];
  var pm = data[2];
  var dd = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(data[3]), "America/New_York", "MMMM dd, yyyy");
  var team1 = data[4];
  var status = data[7];
if (team1 == "Task Completed" && status !== EMAIL_SENT){
  var htmlBody;
  htmlBody = "Project Name: "+pName+"<br>"+"Project ID: "+pID+"<br>"+"Project Manager: "+pm+"<br>"+"Due Date: "+dd+"<br>";
  var optAdvancedArgs = {replyTo: replyTo, cc: cc, name: "Test Email", htmlBody: htmlBody};
  //Logger.log(htmlBody);
  //Logger.log(optAdvancedArgs);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Question, are sh2Range.length and sh1Range.length the same value? if so it might be easier to build it all into one 'for' loop, otherwise you'll be looking at creating objects (Or possibly arrays, but I believe that's bad practice for named values.)

Comment: `sh2Range.length` loops the values in **sheet 2** and `sh1Range.length` loops the values in **sheet 1**. Are you saying the variable names should be changed? Can you show an example to loop through sheet1 and sheet2 in one `for` loop?

Comment: Sorry, for clarification, I mean, are sh2Range and sh1Range the same length? It seems to me as though they should be, and if they consistently are, then it would be easier for you to loop through everything in one.

Comment: Maybe if you see the sample sheet you can see what I am trying to achieve. [My Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FALqlClI33h48vpMgXRKjr24ltNeKwruPylC5RCGz0A/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is a little broad, and there are many ways to do what you're looking for. It's tough to say what you should choose when the specifics of your application aren't clear, such as how many addresses are going to be on Sheet 2, and if you really need to go through an 'if' statement, but I'll offer two potential solutions here that may be of use.

**Solution 1:** What I was trying to ascertain in my comments above was if the email addresses list would be the same length as the list of projects (For example, if there are 10 projects on sheet 1, does that mean there are 10 rows of email addresses in sheet 2). It's still not clear to me, as you have a list of email addresses in your 'CC' address, yet only one in your 'Send to' and 'Reply to' addresses (so you don't really need to loop through the whole range, but perhaps that's required for some other part of the project). However, if that IS the case, then you can actually do all of this in one 'for' loop:

```
//sheet1 Data Loop and Send Email
for (var j = 0; j < sh1Range.length; ++j){
  var data = sh1Range[j];
  var pName = data[0];
  var pID = data[1];
  var pm = data[2];
  var dd = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(data[3]), "America/New_York", "MMMM dd, yyyy");
  var team1 = data[4];
  var status = data[7];
if (team1 == "Task Completed" && status !== EMAIL_SENT){
  var emails = sh2Range[i];
  var to = emails[0];
  var cc = emails[1];
  var replyTo = emails[2];
  var htmlBody;
  htmlBody = "Project Name: "+pName+"<br>"+"Project ID: "+pID+"<br>"+"Project Manager: "+pm+"<br>"+"Due Date: "+dd+"<br>";
  var optAdvancedArgs = {replyTo: replyTo, cc: cc, name: "Test Email", htmlBody: htmlBody};
  //Logger.log(htmlBody);
  //Logger.log(optAdvancedArgs);
    }
   }
```

**Solution 2:** Otherwise, you could place the email addresses into an array when you loop through them:

```
 var addresses = [];

for (var i = 0; i < sh2Range.length; ++i){
  var emails = sh2Range[i];
  var to = emails[0];
  var cc = emails[1];
  var replyTo = emails[2];
  addresses.push([to,cc,replyTo])
 }
```

Which will then allow you to access them using the bracket notation 'addresses[0][0]' later in the script:

```
 var optAdvancedArgs = {replyTo: addresses[0][2], cc: addresses[j][1], name: "Test Email", htmlBody: htmlBody};
```

Both these solutions make a lot of presumptions on what you're doing, but they might guide you to either the answer you're looking for, or possible give you a more concrete idea of what kind of question you're asking.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to show and explain. Solution 2 seems to almost work for me.

Comment: Its likely that you'll experience an issue with the var optAdvancedArgs as it uses 'cc: addresses[j][1]' but the for loop is likely to make 'j' a higher number then the amount of addresses you have. To fix that you need to understand the relationship between the projects on sheet1 and the email addresses on sheet2, which i don't, so you may have to logic that one out yourself, or more clearly explain how they relate.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to show and explain. Solution 2 seems to almost work for me. Full explanation of the application I am trying to build. I have a team of 10 users with different email addresses. They will fill out columns A - D. Each team member will select one of the options in the drop down menus in colmn E - F. If "Request Sent" is select column H will be updated with EMAIL_SENT and a email will be sent to another team. Other members (supervisors, manager and team leader) must be cc in this email. they must reply to a specific email address. Sheet 2 contains those emails

Comment: Caught that and changed it to 'cc: addresses[0][1]', but here is what I am trying to achieve with the emails. For now, the send `to` field is one email address, but may be more. Same applies for `cc` column. I need the `cc` column to be `(user1@gmail.com, user2@gmail.com, user3@gmail.com, user4@gmail.com)`. Right now each `cc` email appear once for each email.

Comment: Update: What I did was put all the `cc` email addresses into one cell and separated with commas. This achieved what I was looking for. Thank you for your help :-)

Comment: Sorry, I'd gone to bed after writing this. Glad I could help, and that you could get it working.